# UITableView Cells not showing properly

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, xcode11, swift5

I've made a table view, and I have a prototype cell that has a height of 100, which I set in the IB.  However the cell displays as the original cell height that the prototype cell is set to by default.  It should be noted that the table view is nested in a UIContainerView, not sure if that's important, but thought it could have to do with something.

Storyboard (in Xcode)
[image]

Simulator
[image]

Comment: check your constraints

Comment: you may not need to return fixed hight '

Comment: Yes.. you don't need to specify the height. If your autolayout constraints are correct, then the tableview will automatically set the correct height

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set height for row

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 100.0;//Choose your custom row height
}
```